# NAS can't connect via switch but works directly on router

Tags: networking, nas, switch

I own a **WD MyCloud 3TB** and a **TP-LINK TL-SG1005D Switch** (10/100/1000Mbps 5-Port Gigabit Desktop Switch) as well as a **Linksys X3000** Modem-Router.

If I attach the NAS to the router it connects without issues. However if I put the switch in-between it won't work. The corresponding port-light on the switch doesn't even light up. I've tried every port, 3 sets of CAT6 cables as well as the one included with the NAS.

That said, I can get it to work by manually turning off autonegotiation (and setting 100/half) by issuing the following command:

```
ethtool -s eth0 speed 100 duplex half autoneg off
```

If I connect the NAS to the switch with this config it is able to connect to my network and works.

What might be the issue here that auto-negotiation seems to fail while connected to the switch?

(Assigning a static IP either on my router and/or the NAS itself has no impact.)

Comment: Does it not work if you issue the command with 1000 full? As both devices are Gigabit, if this doesnt work that is probably why the autoneg is failing as it will detect 1000 full, switch probably is not smart enough to do proper autoneg like a commercial cisco switch would. I would guess its seeing gigabit ethernet and autoneg'in wrong.

Comment: We have this issue with a few PCs on our network (enterprise). The only fix is to set 100mbps full rather than 1Gbps or auto - as you have already found.

Comment: No, setting it to full (1000 or 100) amounts to an ungodly amount of collisions/retransmits. It connects just completely unusable to eg stream a movie